# How to rotate a bitmap on canvas without deform it on Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, rotation

I'm rotating a bitmap on the canvas using a matrix as follows:

```
public void drawRotatedPixmap(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y, int srcX, int srcY, int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int degrees)
{
    srcRect.left = srcX;
    srcRect.top = srcY;
    srcRect.right = srcX + srcWidth;
    srcRect.bottom = srcY + srcHeight;

    dstRect.left = x;
    dstRect.top = y;
    dstRect.right = x + srcWidth;
    dstRect.bottom = y + srcHeight;

    matrix.reset();
    matrix.setRotate(degrees, x+srcWidth/2, y+srcHeight/2);

    canvas.setMatrix(matrix);               
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, dstRect, null);
    canvas.setMatrix(null);
}
```

The original bitmap image is quite pixelated and rotating it I get this:

[image]

By this way the image is rescaling and is quite noticeable at the edges.
The result I would get is the following:

[image]

It is posibile do this by drawing on the canvas or should I use openGL?

Note: sprite image is only for testing and taken from google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you're taking is absolutely fine. However it looks to me like the original graphic is already fuzzy - I daresay it has been a JPG at some point in its life. Note in particular that the edges to the black borders are anti-aliased - they should be black pixels and white pixels but no grey ones.

I believe the rotation algorithm uses sampling to produce the output - this sampling algorithm is interacting with the fuzzy edge producing the undesirable visual artefacts. I bet it will be great if you try again with a sharp original.

There is one more thing to consider: Using a **small** bitmap and upscaling with rotation. This might go against the advice of other responders, but bear with me for a minute.

The typical scaling algorithm used is typically bi-linear interpolation - it's great for photos but pixelated images look horribly soft. However there are a few other algorithms - go to [Wiki: Image Scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) and look at the hqx. This is an example of bi-linear vs. HQX in the game space:

[image: this game]

If this is acceptable, then we have to go to OpenGL, because the Android Canvas and Bitmap functions don't support these algorithms. Potentially a lot of work, but maybe worth your while.

Answer (score 4):

To get higher quality, use a filtered paint:

```
Paint filterPaint = new Paint();
filterPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, dstRect, filterPaint);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can really avoid the pixilating effects with bitmap images. You might reduce the effect by having a sprite drawn at a very high resolution, doing the rotation and then scale the image down. If you have a vector (SVG) version of the image you could rotate that before converting to a bitmap and store a bunch of rotated versions.

You should be able to rotate by 90 without pixilating effects.